# Backup SQL Server directly to CD-RW?

Tags: sql-server, backup

Is it possible to backup a SQL Server database directly to CD-RW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, as long as the SQL Agent can see it with a drive letter and the disc has been prepped for writing.  It won't do your disc prep and finalization though, if that's what you're wondering.